# Null pointer Exception with Page Factory

Tags: selenium-webdriver, page-factory

I was doing some coding to learn PageFactory, but I am getting this error when trying to call a method in another class using page factory

Below is my Elements class:

```
    package pulse.pom.tpr;

    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
    import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class PulseElements {

        WebDriver driver;
        public Actions actions;

        // Login Page Elements
        @FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = "userId")
        WebElement userid;
        @FindBy(name = "password")
        WebElement password;
        @FindBy(name = "dcNumber")
        WebElement dcnbr;
        @FindBy(css = "body > ion-app > ng-component > ion-nav > page-login > ion-content > div.scroll-content > ion-card > ion-grid > form > ion-list > div.login-button > button > span")
        WebElement login;

        // TPR button Element
        @FindBy(id = "tab-t0-2")
        WebElement tpr;

        // Send Associate button
        @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='tabpanel-t0-2']/tpr-summary-page/ion-header[2]/ion-grid/ion-row/ion-col[3]/ion-row/button[1]")
        WebElement sendasc;

        // Next Button after selecting associate
        @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='footers']/ion-toolbar/div[2]/ion-row/ion-col[2]/button")
        WebElement next1;

        // Next Button after selecting Area
        @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='tabpanel-t0-2']/tpr-send-associates-page/div/ion-footer/button")
        WebElement next2;

        // Clockin Button

        @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id='tabpanel-t0-2']/tpr-send-associates-page/ion-content/div[2]/div/div/ion-row[2]/ion-col/div[1]")
        WebElement clockin;

        public PulseElements(WebDriver driver) {
            this.driver = driver;
            actions = new Actions(driver);
        }

        @Test(priority = 1)
        public void pulseLogin(String uid, String pwd, String dc) {

            actions.moveToElement(userid).click().sendKeys(uid);
            actions.build().perform();
            actions.pause(java.time.Duration.ofSeconds(1));
            actions.moveToElement(password).click().sendKeys(pwd);
            actions.build().perform();
            actions.pause(java.time.Duration.ofSeconds(1));
            actions.moveToElement(dcnbr).click().sendKeys(dc);
            actions.build().perform();
            actions.pause(java.time.Duration.ofSeconds(1));
            actions.moveToElement(login).click();
            actions.build().perform();

        }

        @Test(priority = 2)
        public void tprClick() {

            actions.moveToElement(tpr).click();
            actions.build().perform();
        }

        @Test(priority = 3)
        public void sendAssociateButton() {

            actions.moveToElement(sendasc).click();
            actions.build().perform();
        }

        public void selectNext1() {
            actions.moveToElement(next1).click();
            actions.build().perform();
        }

        public void selectNext2() {
            actions.moveToElement(next2).click();
            actions.build().perform();
        }

        public void selectClockin() {

            actions.moveToElement(clockin).click();
            actions.build().perform();
        }

    }
```

And below is my 1st test class for my login page:

```
    package pulse.pom.tpr;

    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;


    public class PulseLogin {

        public WebDriver driver;
        //public PulseElements locateElements=PageFactory.initElements(driver, PulseElements.class);

        @Test(priority=1)
        public void pulseLoginPage() throws InterruptedException
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                    "C:\\MyChromeDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver=new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://mysite/");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            PulseElements locateElements=PageFactory.initElements(driver, PulseElements.class);
            locateElements.pulseLogin("sysadmin", "1234#", "7036");
            locateElements.tprClick();
            locateElements.sendAssociateButton();

        }

        @Test(priority=2)
        public void selectAssociate() {
            System.out.println("Please select any associate");
            Scanner asc = new Scanner(System.in);
            asc.close();
        }

        @Test(priority=3)
        public void selectNextButton1(){
            PulseElements locateElements=PageFactory.initElements(driver, PulseElements.class);
            locateElements.selectNext1();
        }

        @Test(priority = 4)
        public void selectArea() {
            System.out.println("Please select area");
            Scanner area = new Scanner(System.in);
            area.close();
        }

        @Test(priority=5)
        public void selectNextButton2()
        {
            PulseElements locateElements=PageFactory.initElements(driver, PulseElements.class);
            locateElements.selectNext2();
        }


    }
```

And my 2nd test class:

```
    package pulse.pom.tpr;

    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;


    public class ClockinToClockout {

        public WebDriver driver;
        public PulseLogin login=PageFactory.initElements(driver,PulseLogin.class);

        @Test(priority=1)

        public void launchBrowser() throws InterruptedException {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                    "C:\\MyChromeDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            login.pulseLoginPage();
            login.selectAssociate();
            login.selectNextButton1();
            login.selectArea();
            login.selectNextButton2();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }

        @Test(priority=2)

        public void makeMove() {

            PulseElements ele=PageFactory.initElements(driver, PulseElements.class);
            ele.selectClockin();
        }
    }
```

Everything else is working fine, but the makeMove() function in my 2nd test class is giving a null pointer exception:

```
PASSED: launchBrowser
FAILED: makeMove
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:51)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.getCoordinates(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.internal.MouseAction.getActionLocation(MouseAction.java:65)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveMouseAction.perform(MoveMouseAction.java:43)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.CompositeAction.perform(CompositeAction.java:36)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions$BuiltAction.perform(Actions.java:641)
    at pulse.pom.tpr.PulseElements.selectClockin(PulseElements.java:100)
    at pulse.pom.tpr.ClockinToClockout.makeMove(ClockinToClockout.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you need to initialise the `PulseElements` at the class level and not at the `@Test` level like you have done it for `PulseLogin` class.

So, initialise the `PulseElements` at the class level like:

```
public class ClockinToClockout {

    public WebDriver driver;
    public PulseLogin login=PageFactory.initElements(driver,PulseLogin.class);
    public PulseElements ele=PageFactory.initElements(driver, PulseElements.class);

    @Test(priority=1)

    public void launchBrowser() throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\MyChromeDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        login.pulseLoginPage();
        login.selectAssociate();
        login.selectNextButton1();
        login.selectArea();
        login.selectNextButton2();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    @Test(priority=2)

    public void makeMove() {
        ele.selectClockin();
    }
}
```

Comment: am getting the below error when I give it like that: Cannot instantiate class pulse.pom.tpr.ClockinToClockout
 at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:30)
 at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:423)

Comment: The reason you're getting a nullpointerexception is because you're attempting to initialize the page object at the class level in the declaration with a null driver.  This suggested solution does the exact same thing.